# Google TV Chrome WebGL support

Tags: webgl, google-tv

Wanted and needed to test webgl in chrome browser, went to a couple of demo sites of webgl but saying your browser doesnt seem to support webgl

Is this true or do I need to update the chrome browser, I see a option for it but there are various Linux distro's for it

Answer (score 2):

The Chrome browser in Google TV does not currently (including the Honeycomb release) support WebGL, sorry.